# Stereo system Depth map (NN) 3D reconstruction with two cameras giving bad mesh

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I am making stereo system with two cameras and MiDas Deep learning model which returns depth map, each get calibrated at the same time and provide stereo map

Code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import glob
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

################ FIND CHESSBOARD CORNERS - OBJECT POINTS AND IMAGE POINTS #############################

chessboardSize = (6,4) #Inner cells
frameSize = (640,480)


# Termination criteria
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)


# Prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((chessboardSize[0] * chessboardSize[1], 3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:chessboardSize[0],0:chessboardSize[1]].T.reshape(-1,2)

objp = objp * 16 # size of cell in mm
#print(objp)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpointsL = [] # 2d points in image plane.
imgpointsR = [] # 2d points in image plane.


imagesLeft = sorted(glob.glob('images/stereoLeft/*.png'))
imagesRight = sorted(glob.glob('images/stereoRight/*.png'))

for imgLeft, imgRight in zip(imagesLeft, imagesRight):

    imgL = cv.imread(imgLeft)
    imgR = cv.imread(imgRight)
    grayL = cv.cvtColor(imgL, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grayR = cv.cvtColor(imgR, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    retL, cornersL = cv.findChessboardCorners(grayL, chessboardSize, None)
    retR, cornersR = cv.findChessboardCorners(grayR, chessboardSize, None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if retL and retR == True:

        objpoints.append(objp)

        cornersL = cv.cornerSubPix(grayL, cornersL, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
        imgpointsL.append(cornersL)

        cornersR = cv.cornerSubPix(grayR, cornersR, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
        imgpointsR.append(cornersR)

        # Draw and display the corners
        cv.drawChessboardCorners(imgL, chessboardSize, cornersL, retL)
        cv.imshow('img left', imgL)
        cv.drawChessboardCorners(imgR, chessboardSize, cornersR, retR)
        cv.imshow('img right', imgR)
        cv.waitKey(500)


cv.destroyAllWindows()

############## CALIBRATION #######################################################

retL, cameraMatrixL, distL, rvecsL, tvecsL = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpointsL, frameSize, None, None)
heightL, widthL, channelsL = imgL.shape
newCameraMatrixL, roi_L = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrixL, distL, (widthL, heightL), 1, (widthL, heightL))

retR, cameraMatrixR, distR, rvecsR, tvecsR = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpointsR, frameSize, None, None)
heightR, widthR, channelsR = imgR.shape
newCameraMatrixR, roi_R = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrixR, distR, (widthR, heightR), 1, (widthR, heightR))

print(cameraMatrixL)
print(newCameraMatrixL)
print()
print(cameraMatrixR)
print(newCameraMatrixR)


########## Stereo Vision Calibration #############################################

flags = 0
flags |= cv.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC
# Here we fix the intrinsic camara matrixes so that only Rot, Trns, Emat and Fmat are calculated.
# Hence intrinsic parameters are the same 

criteria_stereo = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# This step is performed to transformation between the two cameras and calculate Essential and Fundamental matrix
retStereo, newCameraMatrixL, distL, newCameraMatrixR, distR, rot, trans, essentialMatrix, fundamentalMatrix = cv.stereoCalibrate(objpoints, imgpointsL, imgpointsR, newCameraMatrixL, distL, newCameraMatrixR, distR, grayL.shape[::-1], criteria_stereo, flags)


# Reprojection Error
mean_error = 0

for i in range(len(objpoints)):
    imgpoints2, _ = cv.projectPoints(objpoints[i], rvecsL[i], tvecsL[i], newCameraMatrixL, distL)
    error = cv.norm(imgpointsL[i], imgpoints2, cv.NORM_L2)/len(imgpoints2)
    mean_error += error


print("Total error: {}".format(mean_error/len(objpoints)))


########## Stereo Rectification #################################################

rectifyScale= 1
rectL, rectR, projMatrixL, projMatrixR, Q, roi_L, roi_R= cv.stereoRectify(newCameraMatrixL, distL, newCameraMatrixR, distR, grayL.shape[::-1], rot, trans, rectifyScale,(0,0))
print(Q)

stereoMapL = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(newCameraMatrixL, distL, rectL, projMatrixL, grayL.shape[::-1], cv.CV_16SC2)
stereoMapR = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(newCameraMatrixR, distR, rectR, projMatrixR, grayR.shape[::-1], cv.CV_16SC2)

print("Saving parameters!")
cv_file = cv.FileStorage('stereoMap.xml', cv.FILE_STORAGE_WRITE)

cv_file.write('stereoMapL_x',stereoMapL[0])
cv_file.write('stereoMapL_y',stereoMapL[1])
cv_file.write('stereoMapR_x',stereoMapR[0])
cv_file.write('stereoMapR_y',stereoMapR[1])
cv_file.write('q', Q)

cv_file.release()
```

There is 10cm in distance between cameras and they both share almost the same baseline, one is bit deeper on Z axis than the other
[image: Setup]
Both camera matrixes and total error of calibration seem to be good

```
[[829.23334573   0.         320.16373913] 
 [  0.         618.52774177 250.13711108]
 [  0.           0.           1.        ]]
[[605.63713704   0.         320.44688502]
 [  0.         608.28836475 253.3957634 ]
 [  0.           0.           1.        ]]
Total error: 0.40797200269886297
```

After I am done with calibration, I proceed to do 3D reconstruction. I am using deep learning model to create depth map and Q matrix from previous stereo calibration to do 3D reprojection

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 

        
#Function that Downsamples image x number (reduce_factor) of times. 
def downsample_image(image, reduce_factor):
    for i in range(0,reduce_factor):
        #Check if image is color or grayscale
        if len(image.shape) > 2:
            row,col = image.shape[:2]
        else:
            row,col = image.shape

        image = cv2.pyrDown(image, dstsize= (col//2, row // 2))
    return image



path_model = "models/"

# Read Network
model_name = "model-f46da743.onnx"; # MiDaS v2.1 Large
#model_name = "model-small.onnx"; # MiDaS v2.1 Small


# Load the DNN model
model = cv2.dnn.readNet(path_model + model_name)


if (model.empty()):
    print("Could not load the neural net! - Check path")


# Set backend and target to CUDA to use GPU
#model.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
#model.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)

cv_file = cv2.FileStorage()
cv_file.open('stereoMap.xml', cv2.FileStorage_READ)

Q = cv_file.getNode('q').mat()
print(Q)
 
# # Webcam
# cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# # Read in the image
# success, img = cap.read()


# cv2.imshow('image', img)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

# img = downsample_image(img, 3)

# cv2.imshow('image', img)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

img = cv2.imread('images/test_r.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

imgHeight, imgWidth, channels = img.shape


# Create Blob from Input Image
# MiDaS v2.1 Large ( Scale : 1 / 255, Size : 384 x 384, Mean Subtraction : ( 123.675, 116.28, 103.53 ), Channels Order : RGB )
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255., (384,384), (123.675, 116.28, 103.53), True, False)

# MiDaS v2.1 Small ( Scale : 1 / 255, Size : 256 x 256, Mean Subtraction : ( 123.675, 116.28, 103.53 ), Channels Order : RGB )
#blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255., (256,256), (123.675, 116.28, 103.53), True, False)

# Set input to the model
model.setInput(blob)

# Make forward pass in model
output = model.forward()

output = output[0,:,:]
output = cv2.resize(output, (imgWidth, imgHeight))

# Normalize the output
output = cv2.normalize(output, None, 0, 1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)

plt.imshow(output,'gray')
plt.show()

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Reproject points into 3D
points_3D = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(output, Q, handleMissingValues=False)
print(len(points_3D))

#Get rid of points with value 0 (i.e no depth)
mask_map = output > output.min()

#Mask colors and points. 
output_points = points_3D[mask_map]
print(len(output_points))
output_colors = img[mask_map]

#Function to create point cloud file
def create_output(vertices, colors, filename):
    colors = colors.reshape(-1,3)
    vertices = np.hstack([vertices.reshape(-1,3),colors])

    ply_header = '''ply
        format ascii 1.0
        element vertex %(vert_num)d
        property float x
        property float y
        property float z
        property uchar red
        property uchar green
        property uchar blue
        end_header
        '''
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(ply_header %dict(vert_num=len(vertices)))
        np.savetxt(f,vertices,'%f %f %f %d %d %d')
 


output_file = 'reconstructedMono.ply'

#Generate point cloud 
create_output(output_points, output_colors, output_file)



# cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Depth map seems to be decent and gives values between 0 and 1
[image: Depth map]

Now for the final result which is Pointcloud I get an odd result which does not make sense
[image: Zoomed out]

Zoomed in
[image: Zoomed in result]

I could even say I get no result at this point.
I am so confused on what the issue is, is it because of the Q matrix maybe or because of the depth map given by the model?

Tiny additional information, in case it helps.The results of printing length of output_points seem to be good
I get 307199 which is 1 point less than the maximum of 480x640

Comment: one camera matrix has fx differing greatly from fy. you should look into that. -- the cx,cy also suggest that you're running them at 640x480... I am positive that both can give you a little more resolution. it's just a minor point though. -- if your disparity map gives values between 0 and 1, then that is not disparity. that is something unknown. disparity is measured in pixels.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz 
Hey there, thank you for your insight.
Cameras are different from eachother therefore their fx, fy are different. One is integrated laptop webcam and other is external webcam as you can see in the question. Disparity map is normalized between 0 and 1 in this part of the code
***output = cv2.normalize(output, None, 0, 1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)***
I am not quite sure what you mean by disparity is measured in pixels here?
The disparity map itself is grayscale image of values between n1 and n2, which in my case are just 0 and 1

Comment: you didn't understand my point about fx and fy differing. please assume that you missed my point and consider my response again. -- same goes for the disparity map. you tagged opencv. what you're doing violates assumptions in opencv. IDK where you got the idea that this should be "normalized" or that you didn't just ruin your data with that operation. please don't insist on doing what you're doing because that *is* the issue. you need to let go of that attempt of yours and instead turn towards official documentation and formal education (books on computer vision theory, not programming apis)

Comment: further, you derive your depth map from an AI (I googled the model name). that's not data, that is the AI guessing wildly. also, that completely ignores the second camera you have. you'd still have to properly determine the scaling. "normalizing" isn't something you "just do". you have to know what it does, why to do it, and when NOT to do it. or just use examples provided by the authors of the model, or contact the authors.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The code itself is not attempt of mine, it's nn disparity map from github repo of a computer vision youtuber https://github.com/niconielsen32/ComputerVision/blob/master/pointClouds/pointCloudsNeuralNetworks.py
I genuinely asked you what you meant by measured in pixels (It seems to have been a missunderstanding on my side because I am using one image here and deriving depth from AI as you have mentioned and not traditionally from two images using StereoSGBM or StereoBM and measuring distance between pixels, I apologize for not being clear here).Thank you for clarifying

Comment: Pardon me again, I was mixing terms here
I am using Depth map in the code, not disparity map. I got confused because I am writing seperate project with disparity map and traditional measure of distance between pixels 
I will edit my post to clarify this mistake